# Using MPLD3 to add graphs into Django projects.

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm working on a Django project where I'd like to get data from CSV's and plot them to pages built using Django's views/ templates. Heres the code I have thus far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

graph = plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
g = mpld3.fig_to_html(graph)
return HttpResponse(g)
```

However when I run this I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Anyone know where I went wrong, or how I can create graphs I can add into pages I already have, and not the page MPLD3 renders for you.

Answer (score 1):

plt.plot returns a list of Line2D objects, not a figure object.

What you want to do is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
fig = plt.figure()
fid=plt.plot([3,1,4,1,5])
mpld3.save_html(fig,"test.html")
mpld3.fig_to_html(fig,template_type="simple")
mpld3.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like write @hck3r, plt.plot returns a list of Line2D objects, not a figure object. You need little modifications of your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
g = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
return HttpResponse(g)
```